# When using rvm ruby 3.0.0 OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

### Description

Hi we are using rvm on macos-big sur AWS ec2 machines but it seems that there is an issue with rvm and openssl

### Steps to reproduce

We installed rvm and ruby via packer

```sh
brew install gpg2
echo " ------------------ GPG2 Installation completed -----------------------"
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.bash_profile && rvm install "ruby-3.0.0"
```

It looks okay

```sh
rvm use 3.0.0
openssl version
which openssl
```

> Using /Users/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0
> /usr/bin/openssl
> LibreSSL 2.8.3

But when I

```sh
git clone https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools.git
ruby ssl-tools/doctor.rb
```

I get an error

> Using /Users/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0
> /Users/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby (3.0.0-p0)
> OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021: /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1
> SSL_CERT_DIR=""
> SSL_CERT_FILE=""
>
> HEAD https://status.github.com:443
> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
>
> The server presented a certificate that could not be verified:
> subject: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
> issuer: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> error code 20: unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> Possible causes:
> `/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' does not exist` /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs/' is empty

When I

```sh
brew doctor
```

I get

> Using /Users/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0
> Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
> with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
> working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!
>
> Warning: Homebrew's "sbin" was not found in your PATH but you have installed
> formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
> Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
>
> Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`:
> /usr/local/etc/gnutls/cert.pem
> /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem

Asked the same question in [github.com/rvm](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5180)

Comment: If the error is true, then it seems pretty explanatory: The cert being used cannot be verified for trust.  Thus, locate a base64 copy of the **[DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA](https://ev-root.chain-demos.digicert.com/info/index.html)** certificate, then add it to the `/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem` file and the `/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs/` folder.  Otherwise, update your `SSL_CERT_DIR` environment variable to point to the correct folder where that CA cert can be found.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution that worked

In ~/.bashrc

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

In ~/.bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

In ~/.zshrc

```
# Avoid warning: Homebrew's "sbin" was not found in your PATH but you have installed formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

In provisioner

```
# Remove broken symlinks before using brew
/usr/local/bin/brew cleanup

/usr/local/bin/brew install gpg2
echo "------------------ GPG2 Installation completed -----------------"
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | /usr/local/bin/gpg --import -
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | /usr/local/bin/gpg --import -
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles
source ~/.bash_profile
```